# How can I format a string in a cell?

Tags: excel, format

I am needing to format a large string of data from Excel in order to put it into Wireshark.

Below is a chunk of data I'm working with:

```
042F3400: AABBCC01 F600AABB CC01F500 08004500  *;L.v.*;L.u...E.
042F3410: 03E8006E 0000FE01 86900A0A 0A010A0A  .h.n..~.........
042F3420: 14020800 12130015 00000000 000000F6  ...............v
042F3430: 6BA4ABCD ABCDABCD ABCDABCD ABCDABCD  k$+M+M+M+M+M+M+M
042F3440: ABCDABCD 00  

                    +M+M.
```

What I need ideally is the middle bit of data to have a space in every second character like the example below:

```
AA BB CC 01 F6 00 AA BB CC 01 F5 00 08 00 45 00
```

I've been stuck with the below formula but it stops working after a specific character limit.

```
=MAB(A1,2,9,2)&" "
```

Comment: Ugh. Does it have to be excel? If it must I'd write a macro or do text to columns for this but really this is the sort of thing I would do in a decent text editor with a regular expression

Comment: So you stop at the first semicolon? but what program is this coming from? may be better to control the output first.

Comment: Please specify upto how many characters do you want to extract from the sample set. Then you can use, Left Search Len functions to extract the string of characters. Then you can use a simple Find and Replace to get spaces between the extracted characters. Give me sample data, I'll give you the solution within minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This formula solution depends on having Office 365 or Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function.

- Your output appears quite regular, where the values to be formatted (after removing all spaces) always start at position ten and consist of 32 characters, so I used those features.
- Removing the spaces allows one to return the 16 pairs of values as an array.
- `TEXTJOIN` can then join that array with a space delimiter.

The formula is an **array** formula.  To enter/confirm an **array formula**, hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>. If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula seen in the formula bar.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),(ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,16))-1)*2+1,2))
```

[image]

[image]

If you have an older version of Excel without the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this UDF:

```
Option Explicit
Function fmtPairs(S As String) As String
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim I As Long
    Dim V

V = Split(S)
sTemp = ""
For I = 1 To 4
    sTemp = sTemp & V(I)
Next I

fmtPairs = Trim(Format(sTemp, WorksheetFunction.Rept("@@ ", 16)))

End Function
```

*If your real data is not as regular as what you have shown, you will need to be more detailed.*

**NOTE**  If you don't have `TEXTJOIN` and really want to avoid VBA, you could use this monster formula (normally entered):

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),1,2)," ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),3,2), " ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),5,2), " ",
MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),7,2)," ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),9,2)," ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),11,2)," ",
MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),13,2)," ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),15,2)," ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),17,2)," ",
MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),19,2)," ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),21,2)," ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),23,2)," ",
MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),25,2)," ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),27,2)," ",MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),29,2)," ",
MID(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""),10,32),31,2))
```